# Relation between torque angle, power angle and power factor

Tags: synchronous, synchronous-motor

Considering a synchronous generator, is there a relation between power angle (angle between V terminal and V induced), torque angle (difference between rotor flux and stator flux) and power factor(current and voltage phase)? A phase diagram of synchronous generator with field voltage, terminal voltage and current is useful to understand relation between power angle and power factor, but nowhere I see torque angle in picture.

My intention is to understand the relation between magnetic and electrical phasors. For example, I think stator current and flux will be on same phase and v terminal and rotor flux will be 90 degree phase shifted. Also, can someone share a link to phasor diagram with magnetic variables.

Comment: Do you have access to Fitzgerald, Kingsley, Umans "Electric Machinery," Chapman "Electric Machinery Fundamentals" or Mohamed E. El-Hawary “Principles Of Electric Machines With Power Electronic Applications”?

Comment: I think that the power angle is the same as the torque angle. That is what the diagrams in the above mentioned references seem to indicate, but I have not been able to find that explicitly stated and explained. I believe angle between the stator flux and the rotor flux is the torque angle.